# Minimise the maximum degree of a vertex in a connected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given N vertices and M edges, how to create a connected graph so that I can minimize the maximum degree of every vertex. A vertex can have at most degree N (self loop and other N-1 edges). Find the maximum degree of vertex in all such possible graphs. Consider all possible values of N and M.

Comment: I suspect the answer is to make the graph as regular as possible so the minimum maximum degree is like $\lceil \frac MN\rceil$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: This same question seems to have come up several times recently.  What is the source?